# Is remix ABI generator still working?

Tags: remix, abi

I have recently used the ABI generator fo remix, but when I copy the ABI and paste it in my Geth I get an error:

var abi=x; // where x is abi copied from remix ethereum website.

However, if I copy the content of "interface" from her (when I use the same smart contract code), and replace it with x above I don't get any error.

**Question**: Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's not related to the ABI especially, but to the file on remix where your code is. I noticed that sometimes, if I paste another code in the tab, it will deploy the old code. Same when I imported files that were previously imported on remix, it seems new files aren't considered when compiling too...

Answer (score 0):

When you compile on remix.ethereum , it will generate artifact folder and in there you can find your compiled smart contract with its abi :>